# Difference of using (--prod and prod) command

Tags: angular8

While production of my file am using

npm run build -- --c prod

npm run build -- --c --prod

above both that --prod and prod difference i need , while run both has been running but --prod fast and prod system hang and taking time and can any one clarify me about using (--)in command prompt

Comment: In such case normally command prompt Example: checking version npm --v and npm -v both works  what a difference of it any one clarify

Answer (score 0):

The **--prod** option will make Angular to make the application much smaller in size.
This is the reason why --prod is faster.

From documentation:

```
--prod=true|false   
Shorthand for "--configuration=production". When true, sets the build configuration to the production target. By default, the production target is set up in the workspace configuration such that all builds make use of bundling, limited tree-shaking, and also limited dead code elimination.
```

For < Angular 5:

ng build --prod --build-optimizer

Comment: Ya techfree we are using Angular 8 we suggest --prod but our production team suggest normal prod may now we simply using prod is build makes any change

Comment: Techfree and also another doubt why of using (--) without of  (--) command prompt its work would you clarify

Comment: --c prod would mean that it is attempted to be run for configuration=prod.You should be having a  prod configuration in your angular.json